# Firebase Phone Authentication Using Multiple Authentication Providers

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

**Introduction**

We've been having trouble using Firebase Auth configured with multiple authentication providers.

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects#use_multiple_projects_in_your_application) specifies that an application can support multiple firebase projects.

**Email Sign In**

We have been able to successfully configure our application so that **email authentication** works with multiple authentication providers.

For example:

```
// Configure secondary app
FirebaseApp.configure(name: "SecondaryAuth", options: options)

// Retrieve newly created app
guard let secondaryApp = FirebaseApp.app(name: "SecondaryAuth") else { return }

// Retrieve an Auth client configured against newly created app
let secondaryAuth = Auth.auth(app: secondaryApp)
```

So calling `secondaryAuth.signIn(withEmail: …, password: …)` is successful and works just fine.

**Phone Sign In**

**The problem we are facing** is related to **phone authentication**.

We have noticed that `PhoneAuthProvider`’s initializer can take in an `Auth` parameter, which leads us to believe that **phone authentication** should work using different authentication providers.

[The documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth) specifies that for phone authentication to work we must:

- Enable phone number sign in on our Firebase projects
- Enable app verification using:

  - Silent Push Notifications
  - reCAPTCHA

We have enabled these requirements and our app’s Firebase projects all support:

- Phone number sign in
- Have properly configured APNS
- Xcode project has correctly configured URL Schemes

The problem we are facing is that after we call `verifyPhoneNumber` by passing the `PhoneAuthProvider` a `secondary auth` like so:
`PhoneAuthProvider.provider(auth: secondaryAuth).verifyPhoneNumber(..., uiDelegate: nil)`

We are receiving this error message:
`'Please register custom URL scheme 'app-1-...' in the app's Info.plist file.'`

Keep in mind that we have specified the proper URL Scheme pertaining to the `secondaryApp` previously mentioned inside the app’s info.plist.